# Convert a JSON bytes object

Tags: python

I'm making an API in Python and it throws me something like this. I already tried with BeautifulSoup and it didn't accept it (neither as bytes nor converted into a string). What can I do?

```
b'[{"cc_emails":["ccc@yyy.com"],"fwd_emails":[],"reply_cc_emails":["ccc@yyy.com"],"fr_escalated":false,"spam":false,"email_config_id":13000000444,"group_id":5000250803,"priority":1,"requester_id":5011075567,"responder_id":null,"source":1,"company_id":13000000455,"status":2,"subject":"[URGENT] - PNR TEAM -4 - XXXXXX","to_emails":["ccc@yyy.com"],"product_id":5000007514,"id":143266,"type":"Communication Partenaire","due_by":"2016-07-01T09:34:05Z","fr_due_by":"2016-06-30T21:34:05Z","is_escalated":false,"description":"<div>PNR xxxxxx HAS TO BE TICKETED ON 30Jun</div>","description_text":"PNR xxxxxE HAS TO BE TICKETED ON 30Jun","custom_fields":{"qualification_n2":"Partenaires","catgorie_produit":"Cie A\xc3\xa9rienne","qualification":"Gestion d\xc3\xa9placement","gestion_sc_htels":null,"client":"VVVVVVV","supplier_ticket":null,"hidden_fieldagentsignature":"Nous vous rappelons que pour toute demande vous pouvez nous contacter par t\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phone au  ou par email \xc3\xa0 ccc@mmm.com","hidden_fieldequipeddie":null,"team":"Team 3"},
"created_at":"2016-06-30T09:34:05Z","updated_at":"2016-06-30T09:34:07Z"},{"cc_emails":["ddd@wwww.com"],"fwd_emails":[],"reply_cc_emails":["ccc@3lll.com"],"fr_escalated":false,"spam":false,"email_config_id":13000000528,"group_id":5000250803,"priority":1,"requester_id":5011075567,"responder_id":null,"source":1,"company_id":13000000455,"status":2,"subject":"[URGENT] - PNR TEAM -4 - X6D2O2","to_emails":["ppp@3iiii.com"],"product_id":5000007514,"id":143265,"type":"Communication Partenaire","due_by":"2016-07-01T09:33:59Z","fr_due_by":"2016-06-30T21:33:59Z","is_escalated":false,"description":"<div>PNR XXXXX HAS TO BE TICKETED ON 30Jun</div>","description_text":"PNR XXXXXX HAS TO BE TICKETED ON 30Jun","custom_fields":{"qualification_n2":"Partenaires","catgorie_produit":"Cie A\xc3\xa9rienne","qualification":"Gestion d\xc3\xa9placement","gestion_sc_htels":null,"client":"PWC","supplier_ticket":null,"hidden_fieldagentsignature":"Nous vous rappelons que pour toute demande vous pouvez nous contacter par t\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phone au  ou par email \xc3\xa0 aaa@lll.com","hidden_fieldequipeddie":null,"team":"Team 3"},"created_at":"2016-06-30T09:33:59Z","updated_at":"2016-06-30T09:34:03Z"}]'
```

Comment: `json.loads(my_string)` should be enough

Comment: print(type(r.content))
content = json.loads(str(r.content))


<class 'bytes'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Can you provide some more context? This looks just like a random text dump. What is thrown exactly? It's your own API, so what would you expect to happen/be transmitted? What have you tried so far? Is it a local call or something like an HTTP based API? Etc.

Comment: @LuisUrea try doing it in more separate steps, `.decode` the bytes object with the correct encoding *then* load it as JSON.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It is an API from a company service. Per register I want to take every value and convert it into a .txt or .csv for a friendly reading. For exemple have all "cc_emails" in the first column, all "fwd_email", etc.

Comment: This works, thanks 
content = codecs.decode(r.content,'utf-8')

jcontent = json.loads(content)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be the answer you are looking for:

```
data_bytes = b'{"greeting":"Hello, computer"}'
data_string = data_bytes.decode('utf-8')
import json
data_dict = json.loads(data_string)
data_dict['greeting']
>>> 'Hello, computer'
```

Answer (score 0):

The bytes object needs to be decoded to a string:

```
content = codecs.decode(r.content,'utf-8')

jcontent = json.loads(content)
```

Comment: You don't need `codecs`, you can just do `json.loads(r.content.decode('utf8'))`